# append string in List<String> contained in a dictionary using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have list which contains objects of type Field i.e. `List<Field>` and my field class is defined as follows:

```
Public Class Field
{
   public string FieldName { get; set; }
   public string FieldValue { get; set; }
}
```

This list is then converted to a dictionary of type `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> myResult = 
       myFieldList.Select(m => m)
      .Select((c, i) => new { Key = c.FieldName, value = c.FieldValue })
      .GroupBy(o => o.Key, o => o.value)
      .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.ToList());
```

I would like to use Linq to append the string values contained in the list as a single string, so technically the dictionary defined above should be defined as `Dictionary<string, string>` but I need a couple of extra steps when appending.

I need to add the `\r\n` in front of each values being appended and I need to make sure that these values including the new line do not get appended if the value is empty i.e.

```
value += (string.IsNullOrEmpty(newval) ? string.Empty : '\r\n' + newVal);
```

Thanks.

T.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried using Aggregate but I just don't seem to be able to use correctly. I either have access to the list or to the string but either way, I'm not sure where to put it in my linq query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
var myResult = myFieldList.GroupBy(o => o.FieldName, o => o.FieldValue)
  .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => string.Join("\r\n", 
                                       grp.Where(x=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))));
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `grp.ToList()` with the logic that takes a sequence of strings and puts it together in the way you want.

The key methods you need are `.Where` to ignore items (i.e. the nulls), and `string.Join` to concatenate the strings together with a custom joiner (i.e. newlines).

Incidentally, you should use `Environment.NewLine` instead of `'\r\n'` to keep your code more portable.

Comment: Funny you should mentioned that i.e. Environment.NewLine... Here I am removing it thinking it was the newbie way to code but I always use this! :) and thanks for the recommendation. You were spot on as well as King King!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of grp.ToList() in the elements selector of ToDictionnary, aggregate everything to a single string there (only do this if you have a reasonable amount of strings in there, not a very high one as it would kill performance)
    // Replace this
    grp.ToList()

```
// With this
grp
    .Where(s=>!string.IsNullOrEmtpy(s)) // drop the empty lines
    .Aggregate((a,b)=>a+'\r\n'+b) // Aggregate all elements to a single string, adding your separator between each
```

Comment: This is *significantly* less efficient compared to `string.Join`. Quadratic instead of linear.

Comment: Aye i know, but fairly irrelevant in most scenarios really (often you're going to sum up 3-4 strings) is why i mentioned not to use this if you're working with large collections. I use this out of habbit really as i use aggregate plenty outside of strings and with strings where join isn't flexible enough but in this case the join solution is better for sure.